# Method doesn't exists while using in subscribe section of Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

1. Angular: calling two service method with forkJoin
2. Try to process the result in another method in subscription
3. Finally calling another method from process method
4. and getting error, that method doesn't exists

Here is the code:

```
onLoad(){
  forkJoin([
    this.service1.getData(),
    this.service2.fetchData(id)
  ]).subscribe(
    this.processData,
    errors => { this.error = true; }, 
    () => { this.loading = false; })
};

processData(response: any){
   recordA = response[0];
   recordB = response[1];
   this.validateData(recordB);
}

validateData(record: any) {
  ... some code here ...
}
```

Note: both the service returning result properly, I check the data.

Here is the error:

> ERROR TypeError: this.validateData is not a function
>   at SafeSubscriber.push../projects/pathToComponentnst/xyzComponent.processData
>   [as _next]

100% sure method is there and working for other methods but only in this scenario it is not working.
What is the SafeSubscriber.push there is error?

Just reproduce the same here [https://stackblitz.com/...](https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-client-module?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), open console to see the error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
.subscribe(
    this.processData,
    ...
```

it changes the scope of `processData`, and the new scope doesn't have a `validateData` method. You have to wrap it in an arrow function to preserve the scope:

```
.subscribe(
    response => this.processData(response),
    ...
```

or use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
.subscribe(
    this.processData.bind(this),
    ...
```

Here's a snippet to demonstrate the behavior:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor () {
    this.funcOne(() => this.funcTwo()) // works
    this.funcOne(this.funcTwo.bind(this)) // works
    this.funcOne(this.funcTwo) // what you're doing, doesn't work
  }
  
  funcOne (func) {
    func()
  }
  funcTwo () {
    this.funcThree()
  }
  funcThree () {
    console.log("success")
  }
}

new MyClass()
```

Answer (score -1):

don't you need to pass processData an argument. otherwise validateData has nothing to validate.

Comment: No, in the .subscribe() function, this.processData is supplied as a callback parameter.