# Cannot read property '' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am currently trying to load a modal after execution of loadModalDialog. I am trying to call it in then section. I get an error

```
Cannot read property 'dialog' of undefined
```

If I call in the following manner , I dont get the above error but get an error related to a dependency in userservice since loadModalDialog initiates a call to the agreement component that looks at a value from execution of 
userService. Hence I need to ensure that this.loadModalDialog() needs to be called after execution of userService. Do I need to pass the instance of this.dialog to the function  loadModalDialog ?

```
  this.userService.load();
  this.loadModalDialog();
```

Component

```
constructor( public dialog: ModalDialogService ) {

    export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
      this.userService.load().then(this.loadModalDialog);
      }));
     }

    private loadModalDialog() {
    const ref = this.dialog.open(AgreementComponent, {
      // size: 'large'
    });
    ref.afterClosed.subscribe(result => {
      console.log('3rd dialog closed', result);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method doesn't exists while using in subscribe section of Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60403280/method-doesnt-exists-while-using-in-subscribe-section-of-angular)

Comment: When you pass the function reference to `then`, it loses its scope.

Comment: Not sure how the above link relates.

Comment: Did you try the solutions in the answer? Either wrap it in an arrow function or use `bind`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dropping the context of `this` when you pass in your function to the `.then` statement.

Your error message is a red flag that `this` isn't what you think `this` is supposed to be. It should be as simple as `.bind(this)` on your `this.loadModalDialog` function.

`this.userService.load().then(this.loadModalDialog.bind(this));`

or

`this.userService.load().then(() => this.loadModalDialog());`